# API Caching and Searching

Tags: php, api, mongodb, caching, php-mongodb

I'm creating a product (in php) that works off of calling an api to pull information needed, I want to cache/save these results into mongodb based off of the query strings used, so that the next call of the same query strings pull from mongodb instead of calling the api again.

My only issue im trying to make sure I cover is this example: Searching John Doe may return John Michael Doe in results, Searching again John Michael Doe I actually want this search to hit the api since it drills down more and the next time John Michael Doe is search to pull from mongo.

I understand how to write the code and make the pulls etc, I just need the theory on storing the caching, should I make a table in mongo that saves each searched query string and do a exact match and if it doesn't find any matches hit the api ?

All help is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a common practice is to hash the query parameters using an md5 and then using this as the key to store the result. Next time somebody sends a query, you hash their query parameters again and check if this key already exists in the db. If yes you serve the result from the db if no you call the API.

```
$key = md5(serialize($queryParams));
```

Comment: Sounds like that would get the job done, should I save the key along with the firstname, middlename, lastname etc? So that I can use those values to search the actual table with the data after a key match?

Comment: You could save the query parameters in case you have a use case were to query for them. There is no way restoring the query parameters from the md5.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the suggestion got my brain going, think i will save the parameters and increment on search just to see which names are searched the most etc. Thanks !